# Javascript Replace text in string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm having some troubles getting regex to replace all occurances of a string within a string.

```
**What to replace:**
href="/newsroom

**Replace with this:**
href="http://intranet/newsroom
```

This isn't working:

```
str.replace(/href="/newsroom/g, 'href="http://intranet/newsroom"');
```

Any ideas?

#### EDIT

My code:

```
str = '<A href="/newsroom/some_image.jpg">photo</A>';
str = str.replace('/href="/newsroom/g', 'href="http://intranet/newsroom"');
document.write(str);
```

Thanks,
Tegan

Comment: I'm not sure if you copied it correcly, but you have missed the single quotation marks in the first string. it should be `str.replace('/href="/newsroom/g', 'href="http://intranet/newsroom"');`

Comment: Wierd it doesnt work for me:
str = str.replace('/href="/newsroom/g', 'href="http://intranet/newsroom"');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slash, like so:

```
str.replace(/href="\/newsroom\/g, 'href=\"http://intranet/newsroom\"');
```

Note that I also escaped the quotes in your replacement argument.

Comment: And, as @Mark Byers points out, you need to assign the result to `str` :)

Comment: syntax highlighting in dreamweaver isn't liking it: str = str.replace(/href="\/newsroom\/g, 'href=\"http://intranet/newsroom\"');

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

- You need to assign the result back to the variable otherwise the result is simply discarded.
- You need to escape the slash in the regular expression.
- You don't want the final double-quote in the replacement string.

Try this instead:

```
str = str.replace(/href="\/newsroom/g, 'href="http://intranet/newsroom')
```

Result:

```
<A href="http://intranet/newsroom/some_image.jpg">photo</A>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 str.replace(/href="\/newsroom/g, 'href=\"http://intranet/newsroom\"')
```

UPDATE:
This will replase only the given string:

```
str = '<A href="/newsroom/some_image.jpg">photo</A>';
str = str.replace(/\/newsroom/g, 'http://intranet/newsroom');
document.write(str);
```

Comment: it works but doesn't leave the image name on the end of the url

[code]
<script>
 str = '<A href="/newsroom/some_image.jpg">photo</A>';
 str = str.replace(/href="\/newsroom/g, 'href=\"http://intranet/newsroom\"');
 document.write(str);
</script>
[code]

Comment: still only getting me a link called photo that goes to http://intranet/newsroom when it should go to http://intranet/newsroom/some_image.jpg

<code> 
<script>
str = '<A href="/newsroom/some_image.jpg">photo</A>'; 
str = str.replace(/href="\/newsroom/g, 'href=\"http://intranet/newsroom\"'); 
document.write(str); 
</script>
</code>